# how to turn fullcalendar into a historical calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I would like to use full calendar as an author's assistant.  That means, at the least, the user should be able to pass an arbitrary date variable (<% @hdate = 'yyyy-mm-dd' %>) and the full calendar app would use @hdate as the date-today.  Is this possible? Where would that variable need to be used, in the view, controller, ??

I am basically using the code from Drifting Rails #42 FullCalendar episode. This is full_calendar.js

```
var initialize_calendar;
initialize_calendar = function() {
$('.calendar').each(function(){
var calendar = $(this);
calendar.fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'prevYear, title, nextYear',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  selectable: true,
  selectHelper: true,
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true,
  events: '/events.json',

  select: function(start, end) {
    $.getScript('/events/new', function() {
      $('#event_date_range').val(moment(start).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm") + ' - ' + moment(end).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"))
      date_range_picker();
      $('.start_hidden').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
      $('.end_hidden').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
    });

    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
  },

  eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
    event_data = { 
      event: {
        id: event.id,
        start: event.start.format(),
        end: event.end.format()
      }
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: event.update_url,
        data: event_data,
        type: 'PATCH'
    });
  },

  eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    $.getScript(event.edit_url, function() {
      $('#event_date_range').val(moment(event.start).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm") + ' - ' + moment(event.end).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"))
      date_range_picker();
      $('.start_hidden').val(moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
      $('.end_hidden').val(moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
    });
    }
  });
  })
 };

 $(document).on('turbolinks:load', initialize_calendar);
```

This is the visitor.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Template" %></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Template" %>">
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
  <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
</header>
<main role="main">
  <div class='container'>
    <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
    <div class="calendar"></div>
    <div id='remote_container'></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Again, I want to be able to modify the calendar defaultDate outside of the assets/../../full_calendar.js container, so that I don't have the problem of needing to precompile to run in production mode.

Comment: Fullcalendar v2 or later has [defaultDate](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/) that can set the starting date of the calendar, or you can use [gotoDate](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/gotoDate/) to jump to an arbitrary date the user could choose

Comment: I have seen that in the docs but I can do not understand how to get it to work.  I tried putting a stanza in the controller where it was defined, but get a rails error.  Put a setting into the view controller <% defaultDATE = '1848-02-02' %> and FC still starts at todays date.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet used to create the calendar? **$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 defaultDate: '1848-02-02'
});** appears to work out OK @ https://jsfiddle.net/sLecvu90/

Comment: Is tha code snippet you request the FC javascript? or something from one of the layout views or the startup?  Assuming the startup, here is the code:

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, I can not post the code do to the length limit.  Can you just tell be where you put what you posted?  I have tried putting that code in the javascript container for FC and it causes FC to display fail.  I have tried the controller, model, helper and view for the event controller.  Here is the latest {$('calendar').fullcalendar({ defaultDate: '1848-02-02' });
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', initialize_calendar);}

Comment: BTW, I did look at your link jsfiddle.net/sLecvu90, but that did not help.

Comment: You can edit your original post above to include the code vs here in a comment. You should be able to use jquery $(document).ready to kick off the above fullcalendar snippet